# Visual Studio 2019 unable to use javascript debegguer

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am trying to debug mvc application with javascript debugger turned on in visual studio 2019, I am getting error [Error Message], my javascript debugger is on and I want to debug in javascript.
Any Solution?
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQrtJ.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to run the setup and repair/install the debugger?

Comment: Yes I did twice, even I reinstall visual studio still no solution.